# How can I find the pixel per inch value in a JPG image?

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, jpeg, ppi

I am trying to validate certain images to not allow images lower than 300 pixels per inch, is there a way to find it on ASP.NET using C#?

Comment: 'Pixels per inch' is not really a good unit of measurement.  I think you mean DPI.

Answer (score 1):

You've got to read EXIF data from the image.

Here you have an example of how you can do it, using ExifLib

[ExifLib - A Fast Exif Data Extractor for .NET 2.0+](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36342/ExifLib-A-Fast-Exif-Data-Extractor-for-NET-2-0)

Be warned that not all jpeg images have the resolution information. And, that even if they have it, you can print them using a completely different resolution. I.e. a pic 200px wide can be printed using 1 inch width is 200dpi. This same image printed using 2 inches is 100dpi, and using 1/2 inch is 400dpi.

**EDIT:** It's even possible to get this info with native .NET framework [Image.PropertyItems Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.propertyitems.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

The `Image` object of the .NET Framework will give you the PPI of a Bitmap (including a JPG).

```
Image image = new Bitmap(@"C:\myimage.jgp");
float ppi = image.HorizontalResolution; // the image's pixels per inch
float widthInInches = image.PhysicalDimension.Width / ppi;
```

Seems to work for me. I was able to discern that a specific image I am using in a PDF is 90 ppi.