# How to detect a corrupted file before opening it in C#

Tags: c#, file, encryption, io

I have some files which have been corrupted and I want to detect which file is corrupted before opening it. I used FileInfor class but useless.

Comment: which type of file u r trying to upload/ download btw?

Comment: How can you detect corruption without opening the file and looking at it?

Comment: It isn't clear what your intention is, but usual way of checking if file is corrupt is to have a hash of the original file. And when you get a copy of it by downloading you can check the hash to know if it's still the same file.

Comment: @Victor, It is not uploading or downloading stuff. I have mainly three types of files as .pdf , .cgm and .mp4. Is there a solution for this issue which is not depended on file type.?

Comment: hey @Senavirathna, i've given a link in solution; check if its helpful

Comment: @Spo1ler, It is correct if there is the original file but for me original one is not there how to determine without opening.?

Comment: @Senavirathna You simply can not. You need to define what is corrupted and what is not and check it when you open it. You can't differentiate corrupt and valid files otherwise.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, I have sometimes 25MB size of .mp4 files. If the file is corrupted program directs it to another process and if not corrupted  then program forces to open it. In this scenario if we open the file before processing the mechanism it is useless. Hence If there is a suitable way to check the file is corrupted then issue is over.

Comment: When you said "open," I didn't realize you meant "play" or "display." The way you check any file for corruption is to examine its structure to see if it conforms to the file specification.  The operating system won't do that for you; all it sees is a bunch of bits.  It doesn't know anything about MP3 or PDF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.** Unfortunately there is no easy way to determine if file is corrupt before even rendering it. Usually the problem files have a correct header so the real reasons of corruption are different. The file contains a reference table giving the exact byte offset locations of each object from the start of the file. So most probably corrupted files have broken offsets or may have some object missing.

The best way to determine that the file is corrupted is to use specialized libraries of that type like PDF file libraries. There are lots of both free and commercial of such libraries for .NET. You may simply try to load file with one of such libraries. `iTextSharp` will be a good choice.

**2.** Or if you want, you can go though this answer :
[File Upload Virus Scanning(server side)](http://forums.asp.net/p/890935/956276.aspx#956276)

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to solve this issue is to have your program have a log file of when it accesses and edits a file. By keeping track of this, if a program exited prematurely, you could easily identify the the saving was interrupted. To do this you should have the program add a new log every time the program *has completed* saving a file, not before it is saved. When the program trys to open the program, you can check the time that the file was last edited and if the last edited time is later than the time logged in the log file, then reject it.

Of course this system will only work on one computer. There are other ways of implementing this such as having a log at the end of the file. If the log does not exist, then you know that the file is corrupt. Open your mind up to more ideas and try to think of some more ways to solve this issue. This is just one example.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to parse the header bytes of the file and make sure it satisfies the rest of the file body contents. e.g.,

[Reading image header info without loading the entire image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14390204/reading-image-header-info-without-loading-the-entire-image)
This is how you can read header of an image and get the image size without opening it. In the same way you should look at the desired file format header and validate it as per the file format rule. This is not the readymade solution but may give you an idea.